# Magento get final price with Cart discount

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, cart

I am working with cross-selling on my shopping cart page.
I have two products: #001 and #002.

Currently, if product #001 is in the cart, the upsell will display a message about #002.

I would like to get #002's finalPrice-(cart rules), so that the price is displayed with the discount, based on the fact that product #001 is in the cart.

How can I subtract the cart discount given on #002?

Currently, with getFinalPrice(), the full price "499,-" is displayed, even though #001 is added to the cart, and has rules that tells #002 to have 50% discount.

Comment: Hi @baoutch - That method sadly doesent exist on the ('salesrule/rule') model, which stores the "Store cart rules". Thanks

Comment: Thats on the ('catalogrule/rule') model, which handles catalog-rules.  As far as i understand, the "Store cart rules" are handled by ('salesrule/rule') model @baoutch